# How to get "region & language" settings in WP7 via code?

Tags: windows-phone-7, settings

Is it possible to get following settings via the API?

- First day of week
- Region format
- Display language
- System locate

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` to find the system culture and language settings respectively. The rest of the information (first day of week etc) is within there, I believe - for example:

```
DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
                                      .DateTimeFormat
                                      .FirstDayOfWeek;
```

Comment: A caveat: In some regions, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name may disagree with Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name - in Australia, for example, UI culture returns en-GB despite my region being set to en-AU.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks for that... interesting and disturbing :(