# Detecting home country of Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to programmatically find out what country a user's phone is from when my app is opened on their phone?

I have an app I'm developing that can use **lbs/kg units** and if someone's phone is from the United States, I want to enable lbs by default and if the phone is from anywhere else, I want to display kg by default. (note that I don't need think checking where they are connecting from would be accurate because it could be that they are travelling or using another country's proxy server).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get the country, but you should be able to guess it from:

- the Locale of the device - see [How to get "region & language" settings in WP7 via code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656911/how-to-get-region-language-settings-in-wp7-via-code)
- or from the TimeZone of the device - see TimeZoneInfo.Local - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.local.aspx

Personally, I wouldn't worry about the travelling scenario - travelling Americans purchasing your app represents a very small percentage of your downloads.

Comment: too bad this is not exactly exposed as a home country field, but looks like Locale will suffice. thx!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the GPS to get their current position, then use the Bing API to get the country from the lat/long.

Using the GPS involves it's own headaches like adding a Privacy Policy, but from Stuart's answer, it seems like the most accurate way.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.DisplayName;`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just look at System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.IsMetric?

There is an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.globalization.regioninfo.ismetric(v=vs.105).aspx