# detecting user settings in wp7/ wp7.1

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to be able to programmatically detect what keyboard settings the user is using (language, sound, vibration of keys) to be able to take actions based on that facts.

is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I think some of the answer is here: [How to get "region & language" settings in WP7 via code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656911/how-to-get-region-language-settings-in-wp7-via-code)

Also this page should help for Vibration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.vibratecontroller%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

Regarding sound settings, not sure you can from a quick search: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/60e0c7f8-c3f0-4938-abd4-8c1c48a52a5a

However this is from a while ago so might have changed since

EDIT: There is something about saving ringtone here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394008%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Though re-reading your question it might be you aren't interested in that.